# Class template instantiation as type template parameter, syntax?

Tags: c++, class, templates, syntax, type-parameter

```
class XY{};

template<typename typeA>
class A
{
(...)
};
template<typename typeB>
class B
{
(...)
};
(...)
     B<class <class XY>A> * attribute; // <- How can I do that without Syntaxerror
```

When trying this gcc gives me the following error:

> xy.h:19: error: template argument 1 is invalid

How can I avoid that?

Comment: correct syntax is `B<A<XY>>* attribute`, if you meant to instance A with XY, and B with `A<XY>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `class` keyword is only for defining a template class, not for declaring an object. For that, you just need:

```
B<A<XY> >* attribute;
```

Or to spread it out for clarity:

```
typedef A<XY> MyA;
typedef B<MyA> MyB;
MyB* attribute;
```

Comment: It's worth noting that `B<A<XY>>* attribute;` is a syntax error before C++11. (For pre-C++11 you would have to do `B< A<XY> >* attribute;`, otherwise the `>>` parses as the right-shift operator. The C++11 grammar was tweaked so that `>>` can parse multiple ways depending on the context.)

Comment: yepp it thinks this is the shifting operator.

Comment: @cdhowie Fixed, I'm used to not typing the space these days.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is quite unclear, but I think you're after *template template parameters*. This way :

```
template <template <class> class U>
class Foo {};
```

Now `Foo` is a class template accepting another class template as its parameter, like so :

```
template <class V>
class Bar {};

Foo<Bar> theFoo;
```

Comment: @MartinErhardt I edited your question's title that misled me, hope that's okay.

Comment: interestingly that's not what I asked for, but what I needed just later in my implemantation.

Comment: But how do I use U inside of Foo?: "error: 'U' does not name a type"

Comment: You need to instanciate `U` (like in `U<Something>`). `U` is an actual template, not any of its instantiations, so it is indeed not a type.